# Wrong Currency symbol in view filter

Tags: views, theming

I have a view with BEF which is generating a criteria box like this below

[image]

I have no clue where this $ sign is coming from and how to remove it or change it.

**Update**

I investigated further and what I have noticed is that the currency symbol is linked to the theme settings. There is a field in the theme settings to accept currency code which was by default EUR. That I changed to INR which is not working but when I change to JPY it shows proper japan yet currency symbol. This confirms that this is the place where we need to look at.

Can some one help me where to start from?

Comment: I think this you need block settings.. You shown "Configure filter criterion" -> For This Page (override ). May be this is not your seeking answer.

Comment: Do you mean. I need to look at block settings not the view settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your currency symbol is most likely coming from the field definition. Check the "prefix" value for the field in question at `admin/structure/types/manage/<content_machine_name>/fields/<field_machine_name>` replacing the items in `<>` as appropriate.

Comment: Thats reflecting change in the view contents but not in the view filters (which is, in my case is search box)

Comment: I further investigated and spotted where that $ sign is coming from. Please see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the symbols were tweaked in the jquery.currency.js

It has format_current function which has a list for mapping 3 Letter currency symbol to actual currency symbol

I have added this line to that mapping list

```
            if(bc == 'INR') currency_before = 'Rs.';
```